# Maps Intents don't show specified location

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with my application. I want to open Google Maps with defined in code location, so I set the data to the intent, but maps open on my location  all the time (not the specified in code one).

Here is the code:

```
String addressString = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, CA";

Uri locationUri = new Uri.Builder();
        .scheme("geo")
        .path("0,0")
        .query(addressString);
        .build();

Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, locationUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Does anyone know how to handle this situation? I tried on my phone and on the virtual device and it's not working on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `query(addressString)` to                 `appendQueryParameter("q", addressString)` and you will rich what you want:

```
Uri locationUri = new Uri.Builder()
        .scheme("geo")
        .path("0,0")
        .appendQueryParameter("q", addressString)
        .build();
```

Comment: @Bartek can you accept my answer? It may help to find other users right answer

Answer (score 1):

Use it this way to open with latitude and longitude:

```
double lat = YOUR_LATITUDE;
double lng = YOUR_LONGITUDE;
String placeLabel = YOUR_PLACE_LABEL;
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f?q=%f,%f(%s)", lat, lng, lat, lng, placeLabel);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to open the map with an address, replace de uri with:

```
geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
```

Comment: Thanks for the first hint!
I just wanted to open with an address, but also using a Uri.Builder and I didn't realize, that I use ".query" instead of ".appendQueryParameter" and now it works :)